# Accessing FCM parameters by toastr

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, toastr

I have notification coming in via FCM in thee following JSON format:

```
    {
      "message":{
        "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
        "notification":{
          "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
          "body":"great match!"
        },
        "data" : {
          "Nick" : "Mario",
          "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
        }
      }
    }
```

I can access the notification title & body using `payload.notification.title`, as in my following code.
but how would I access other parameters in the **`data`** section?

```
// Handle incoming messages
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log("Notification received: ", payload);
  toastr["success"](payload.notification.body, payload.notification.title, {
      "closeButton": true,
      "debug": false,
      "newestOnTop": false,
      "progressBar": true,
      "positionClass": "toast-top-left",
      "onclick": payload.notification.click_action, // I also tried removing this
      "preventDuplicates": false,
      "showDuration": 30000,
      "hideDuration": 1000,
      "timeOut": 0,
      "extendedTimeOut": 0,
      "showEasing": "swing",
      "hideEasing": "linear",
      "showMethod": "fadeIn",
      "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
       });  
});
```

Comment: `payload.data.Nick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all just a JSON object, so you can access the data properties with `payload.data.Nick` and `payload.data.Room`.